# php is not getting custom headers (Apache 2.4 + FPM/FastCGI php 7)

Tags: php, http-headers, apache2, apache2.4, request-headers

I have tried to get all headers by using apache_request_headers(), $_SERVER, $_ENV and getallheaders().

I know that Apache 2.4 is dropping unknown headers for security reasons and tried to circumvent it by adding:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ^X (.*) HTTP_CUSTOM=$0
RequestHeader set HTTP_CUSTOM %{HTTP_CUSTOM}e env=HTTP_CUSTOM
```

which successfully catches/renames known headers, but when trying to catch an X-Custom-Header, it is always empty.

What could be the cause?

Comment: What returns the command : `apache2ctl -V` ?
Have you tested it with add or merge ?
`RequestHeader add HTTP_CUSTOM %{HTTP_CUSTOM}e env=HTTP_CUSTOM`

Comment: @logic did my answer work?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not actually sure what you are trying to do.

If you are trying to add headers that start with X from your request to your response then I would use this in your htaccess file.

```
Header echo ^X
```

If you are trying to use header values in your PHP script then they should be in your `$_SERVER` array, but the names are normalized. E.G

```
X-Custom-Header: blah
X-Na-Bra: true
```

can be accessed from

```
<?php 
   // note that headers are prefixed with "HTTP" and "-" and changed to "_"
   echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CUSTOM_HEADER'];
   echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_NA_BRA'];

  // either way you should be able to find them with a print_r($_SERVER);
  // print_r(getallheaders()); should show the headers without normalized names
  $tempArray = getallheaders();
  echo $tempArray['X-Custom-Header'];
?>
```

It sounds like you want to get the values from a dynamic number of headers that start with X. If this is the case then your code won't work either way. Your code (if it worked) would always contain the **last** value of a header that starts with X. So if you have more than 1 header that starts with X then you would be missing values. Using your code, you would need to create a rule for each header that you wanted to pass to your PHP script, which sounds like a pain.

If i'm missing something then comment below and I'll update this answer.